# Why did the Planck spacecraft choose those specific frequency bands?

Tags: cosmology

The Planck spacecraft has two instruments, the Low Frequency Instrument (LFI) and the High Frequency Instrument (HFI). The LFI makes use of 3 frequency bands (30, 45 and 70 GHz) whereas the HFI makes use of 6 frequency bands (100, 143, 217, 353, 545 and 857 GHz). I know that for the HFI, 100-353 GHz bands can measure polarization of the photons, whereas 545 and 857 GHz bands cannot.

There are some frequencies which correspond to dust; and I recognize that several frequency bands are used to try and isolate (and subtract) various foreground effects (e.g. SZ, ISW, free-free emission), but I was just wondering which frequencies corresponds to which foreground 'type'? A brief search did not inform me of anything.